# RocketMQ connection to Z/OS IBM MQ queues

Tags: mq, zos, rocketmq

Has anyone successfully connected the 4.x version of RocketMQ to IBM MQ queues on Z/OS using the JMS connectivity?  What issues did you encounter and what were the specific use cases/patterns enabled?  Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Do you mean building sort of bridge between z/OS MQ and RocketMQ?

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific error are you encountering?

Comment: @Shashi - I would think a bridge might be one alternative, just looking to see what others have done.  We have a strong MQ presence on Z/OS with IBM MQ, I'd like to see what others have done and what is available to integration with RocketMQ that is JMS 2.0 compliant per the documentation.